# Dynamical System

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm Trying to solve dynamical system in friedmann universe. But, I have problems with initial conditions to $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ and $\Omega_{k}$. The code that i'm implementing is

```
ode1[x0_, y0_] := NDSolve[{x'[n]] == 2 (1 + (3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/2 x[n]) x[n],  y'[n] ==  2 ((3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/ 2 x[n]) y[n], x0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[n], y[n]}, {n, -0.7, 0.54}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Where $\gamma=1$, $n=\ln a$, $x=\Omega_{\Lambda}$ and .$y=\Omega_{k}$ For example, I try

```
sol[1] = ode1[-0.5, 1.5]; sol[2] = ode1[1, 0]; sol[3] = ode1[0, 1]; sol[4] = ode1[0.8, 0.2]; sol[5] = ode1[-0.3, 1.3]; sol[6] = ode1[1.3,-0.3]; sol[7] = ode1[1.2, -0.2]; sol[8] = ode1[0.2, 0.8];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{x[n], y[n]} /. sol[i], {i,8}]], {n, -0.7, 0.54}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 100, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> True]
```

The plot shows anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use code

```
ode1[x0_, y0_] := 
 NDSolve[{x'[n] == 
     2 (1 + (3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/2 x[n]) x[n],
     y'[n] == 
     2 ((3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/2 x[n]) y[n], 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0} /. \[Gamma] -> 1, {x, y}, {n, -0.7, 0.54},
   MaxSteps -> Infinity]
sol[1] = ode1[-0.5, 1.5]; sol[2] = ode1[1, 0]; sol[3] = ode1[0, 1]; 
sol[4] = ode1[0.8, 0.2]; sol[5] = ode1[-0.3, 1.3]; 
sol[6] = ode1[1.3, -0.3]; sol[7] = ode1[1.2, -0.2]; 
sol[8] = ode1[0.2, 0.8];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[{x[n], y[n]} /. sol[i], {i, 8}]], {n, -0.7, 0.54}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Phase space of the system

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  1 - x - y < 0 && -.5 <= x <= 1.5 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]; reg1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  1 - x - y > 0 && -.5 <= x <= 1.5 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];

sp = StreamPlot[{2 (1 + (3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/
         2 x[n]) x[n], 
    2 ((3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/2 x[n]) y[
      n]} /. \[Gamma] -> 1, {x[n], y[n]} \[Element] reg1, 
  FrameLabel -> {Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalLambda]], 
    Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], K]}, StreamPoints -> Fine]

rp = Show[RegionPlot[reg, BoundaryStyle -> None], 
  Graphics[{Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 2], 
    Inset[\[CapitalOmega] < 0, {1, 0.5}]}]]
Show[sp, rp]

sp1 = StreamPlot[{2 (1 + (3 \[Gamma] - 2)/2 (1 - y[n]) - (3 \[Gamma])/
         2 x[n]) x[n], 1 - x[n] - y[n]} /. \[Gamma] -> 1, {x[n], -.5, 
   1.5}, {y[n], 0., 2}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalLambda]], \
\[CapitalOmega]}, StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

[image: Figure2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that I want to reproduce the figure 2 [link] (http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0108066v1) in page 13.

Comment: @Fisjog Show how to do it?

Comment: thanks a lot! @alex-trounev